# Tomcat understands amq:broker but Eclipse marks errors in schema

Tags: java, eclipse, activemq-classic, springsource

When working with ActiveMQ in Eclipse, you might sometimes get a schema parsing error as such:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c:
The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'amq:broker'.
```

However, the project deploys successfully in Tomcat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix this, you must associate the ActiveMQ XSD URL with the schema.

Go to XML->XML Catalog in Preferences, and add a User Specified Entry.

```
Location: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.3.0.xsd
Key Type: Namespace Name
Key: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
```

Then add a second one:

```
Location: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.3.0.xsd
Key Type: Schema Location
Key: http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
```

Hit OK.

If you have this same error and Tomcat fails, open the applicationContext-jms.xml file which triggers the error and replace:

```
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.2.0.xsd
```

with

```
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd
```

Comment: Answer obtained from http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/02/01/invalid-activemq-schema-name-space comments. See his solution, which uses local jar, if this one does not work for you. Answered my own question.