# how to associate the activemq-core.xsd url with the activemq.xsd found in the jar file?

Tags: activemq-classic

Somebody knows how to associate the **activemq-core.xsd** url with the **activemq.xsd** found in the jar file (activemq-core-5.2.0.jar)?

I dig some solution in internet but didn't work.

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 19 in XML document from class path resource [jms-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'amq:broker'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:81)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:173)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:197)
```

This shoud me hapening because we remove the URL from the schemaLocation *(http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core classpath:activemq.xsd)*, and we are using localy. But I don't know why XML are not finding the activemq.xsd during the build process. I add the JAR file in the classpath, should not work like that??

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this question?
[Tomcat understands amq:broker but Eclipse marks errors in schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289532/tomcat-understands-amqbroker-but-eclipse-marks-errors-in-schema/2289556#2289556)
(my own question, followed up with my solution)

I think that's the same problem you are having. I was able to fix it after adding those entries to the XML Catalog.